# IBM MQ put and get messages via REST API

Tags: java, rest, ibm-mq

I want to removed the ibm.mq.client lib dependencies for **get** and **put** messages in to IBM MQ. So i hope to make REST call for put and get messages.

I went through [WebSphere MQ bridge for HTTP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q033180_.htm) this is not worked for me, This will gave to me WebSphere Application Server dependence(not able to deploy on the Apache tomcat server). could please let me know how can i use reset API call to get and put message to IBM MQ with out ibm lib/server dependence

Comment: IBM says that "WebSphere MQ bridge for HTTP runs on any Java EE 1.4 compliant application server, by installing the WebSphere MQ resource adapter." I don't think that Tomcat supports JCA resource adapters, so that might be where you came unstuck. However, I believe that TomEE does, and I'm certain that Wildfly/EAP does. So I think there are open-source webservers that should be able to host the MQ bridge, if you don't want to use W-MQ. If you don't want to use the MQ bridge, or can't, then there's really no alternative but to implement your own servlet that does the HTTP-MQ conversion, I think

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this answer, MQ V9.0.3.0 is the latest release of the MQ Continuous Delivery product stream.  This version does not offer a REST API to put/get messages beyond that provided by the MQ bridge for HTTP (which was deprecated at MQ v8).

Are you a member of the IBM MQ Beta Programme?  (It might be called the Early Access Programme, I can't remember).

http://www-05.ibm.com/uk/earlyprograms/

There are lots of interesting things you can learn about what may be coming next and you'll have the opportunity to participate in shaping the plans and provided feedback on what you hear about!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you could give a try to [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=directory) that, among many other features, allows the user to deal with JMS Messages via  a REST interface